# OSX Composer Cakephp 3.4.2 setup issue

Tags: macos, homebrew, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to create cakephp 3.4.2 project with composer using OS X Sierra 10.12.5.

I get error:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.2 requires lib-icu >=4.8 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.1 requires lib-icu >=4.8 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.4.0 requires lib-icu >=4.8 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.4.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.4.5, 3.4.6].
```

However when `I run brew install php56-intl`
I get:

```
Error: /usr/local/Cellar is not writable. You should change the
ownership and permissions of /usr/local/Cellar back to your
user account:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
Warning: homebrew/php/php56-intl-5.6.30_7 already installed
```

Since I use just "normal" user account, don't have this in sudoers and have separate administrator account, I installed home-brew and php56 intl using that administrator account.

Comment: https://codingexplained.com/dev-ops/mac/installing-php-intl-extension-os-x-mavericks
 this might help you!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same problem.. Try this:

- Copy all `icu*.dll` files from php directory to your `server/bin` directory.
- Edit `php.ini` removing the comma (;) of `extension=php_intl.dll`.
- Restart http server.
- Run composer again.

Should work